# concatenating firebase request

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm observing a child value in firebase, after receiving a child I need to look to other properties in another ref, inside the first request.

This is the firebase structure:

```
    {
  "chats" : {
    "11-126" : {
      "-LJZTRGt4lqMFjfgQqH0" : {
        "attachmentType" : 6,
        "body" : "kdnfif",
        "date" : 1533915284798,
        "delivered" : false,
        "id" : "-LJZTRGt4lqMFjfgQqH0",
        "loaded" : true,
        "managed" : false,
        "recipientId" : "11",
        "selected" : false,
        "senderId" : "126",
        "senderName" : "Porter Project",
        "sent" : true,
        "valid" : true
      }
    },
    "121-123" : {
      "-LK7DHLChxxqKLvn4dRa" : {
        "attachmentType" : 6,
        "body" : "Hola",
        "date" : 1534515029389,
        "delivered" : true,
        "id" : "-LK7DHLChxxqKLvn4dRa",
        "loaded" : true,
        "managed" : false,
        "recipientId" : "123",
        "selected" : false,
        "senderId" : "121",
        "senderName" : "Yoel",
        "sent" : true,
        "valid" : true
      },
      "-LK7ELGPbdext9hyliAh" : {
        "attachment" : {
          "bytesCount" : 51302,
          "loaded" : true,
          "managed" : false,
          "name" : "IMG-20180816-WA0002.jpeg",
          "url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/roomatch-209023.appspot.com/o/RooMatch%2FImage%2FIMG-20180816-WA0002.jpeg?alt=media&token=3baa3bdd-4280-4e6f-b190-bddd4fcffc17",
          "valid" : true
        },
        "attachmentType" : 2,
        "date" : 1534515306654,
        "delivered" : false,
        "id" : "-LK7ELGPbdext9hyliAh",
        "loaded" : true,
        "managed" : false,
        "recipientId" : "121",
        "selected" : false,
        "senderId" : "123",
        "senderName" : "Chab1",
        "sent" : true,
        "valid" : true
      },
      "-LK8z6O3HFp9ckfwaqnD" : {
        "attachmentType" : 6,
        "body" : "Un texto",
        "date" : 1534544606647,
        "delivered" : true,
        "id" : "-LK8z6O3HFp9ckfwaqnD",
        "loaded" : true,
        "managed" : false,
        "recipientId" : "123",
        "selected" : false,
        "senderId" : "121",
        "senderName" : "Yoel",
        "sent" : true,
        "valid" : true
      },
      "-LKFHdpEFat-eX7xAQdu" : {
        "attachmentType" : 6,
        "body" : "recibido texto",
        "date" : 1534650391854,
        "delivered" : false,
        "id" : "-LKFHdpEFat-eX7xAQdu",
        "loaded" : true,
        "managed" : false,
        "recipientId" : "121",
        "selected" : false,
        "senderId" : "123",
        "senderName" : "Chab1",
        "sent" : true,
        "valid" : true
      },
      "-LKRy6pZwjNnvJwx43Bn" : {
        "attachmentType" : 6,
        "body" : "jjj",
        "date" : 1534863113383,
        "delivered" : false,
        "id" : "-LKRy6pZwjNnvJwx43Bn",
        "loaded" : true,
        "managed" : false,
        "recipientId" : "121",
        "selected" : false,
        "senderId" : "123",
        "senderName" : "Chab1",
        "sent" : true,
        "valid" : true
      },
      "-LKRze2KNk8xdgsdmq-B" : {
        "attachmentType" : 6,
        "body" : "gfx",
        "date" : 1534863515671,
        "delivered" : false,
        "id" : "-LKRze2KNk8xdgsdmq-B",
        "loaded" : true,
        "managed" : false,
        "recipientId" : "121",
        "selected" : false,
        "senderId" : "123",
        "senderName" : "Chab1",
        "sent" : true,
        "valid" : true
      },
      "-LKRzmsc5vPBxeJdneNQ" : {
        "attachment" : {
          "bytesCount" : 51125,
          "loaded" : true,
          "managed" : false,
          "name" : "IMG-20180816-WA0000.jpeg",
          "url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/roomatch-209023.appspot.com/o/RooMatch%2FImage%2FIMG-20180816-WA0000.jpeg?alt=media&token=688f8d78-5419-4986-8b21-1e030a0b9da4",
          "valid" : true
        },
        "attachmentType" : 2,
        "date" : 1534863551851,
        "delivered" : false,
        "id" : "-LKRzmsc5vPBxeJdneNQ",
        "loaded" : true,
        "managed" : false,
        "recipientId" : "121",
        "selected" : false,
        "senderId" : "123",
        "senderName" : "Chab1",
        "sent" : true,
        "valid" : true
      }
    }},
  "users" : {
    "121" : {
      "id" : "121",
      "image" : "",
      "loaded" : true,
      "managed" : false,
      "name" : "Yoel",
      "nameToDisplay" : "Yoel Jimenez",
      "online" : true,
      "selected" : false,
      "status" : "Added!",
      "typing" : false,
      "valid" : true
    },
    "122" : {
      "id" : "122",
      "image" : "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-RX7ka61PxvY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADw/8d1DyKgF4y4/photo.jpg?sz=50",
      "loaded" : true,
      "managed" : false,
      "name" : "QtJambiii",
      "nameToDisplay" : "QtJambiii",
      "online" : false,
      "selected" : false,
      "status" : "Added!",
      "typing" : false,
      "valid" : true
    },
    "123" : {
      "id" : "123",
      "image" : "http://www.freecashrewards.co/roomatch/api/photo/HO8rxjXhMHConKe2BG3GItNoHDZ6ENs9LqJHlZRj.jpeg",
      "loaded" : true,
      "managed" : false,
      "name" : "Chab1",
      "nameToDisplay" : "Chab1",
      "online" : false,
      "selected" : false,
      "status" : "Added!",
      "typing" : false,
      "valid" : true
    },
    "124" : {
      "id" : "124",
      "image" : "",
      "loaded" : true,
      "managed" : false,
      "name" : "Leo",
      "nameToDisplay" : "Leo",
      "online" : false,
      "selected" : false,
      "status" : "Added!",
      "typing" : false,
      "valid" : true
    },
    "125" : {
      "id" : "125",
      "image" : "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-9Mi0fhtOqMQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AAnnY7pGdlGynOdTmxd6p3MflUn0BXjjww/mo/photo.jpg?sz=50",
      "loaded" : true,
      "managed" : false,
      "name" : "Oscar",
      "nameToDisplay" : "Oscar",
      "online" : false,
      "selected" : false,
      "status" : "Added!",
      "typing" : false,
      "valid" : true
    },
    "131" : {
      "id" : "131",
      "image" : "",
      "loaded" : true,
      "managed" : false,
      "name" : "Marta",
      "nameToDisplay" : "Optional(\"Marta\") Optional(\"gr\")",
      "online" : true,
      "selected" : false,
      "status" : "Added!",
      "typing" : false,
      "valid" : true
    }
  }
}
```

I'm reading for chats all children, then if the child id has some string that I need I extract the values of the child, the child has a value recipientId which is a user id in users child. I need to retrieve the user values of the child with id equal to recipientID. I'm tried different approachs but all return nil.

Here is the code I tried:

```
chatsRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { [weak self] snapshot in
            if snapshot.key.contains(String(requestManager.instance.user.id!)){
                if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]{
                    for snap in snapshot{
                        if let data = snap.value as? [String: Any]{
                            let id = data["id"] as! String

                            let message = data["body"] as? String
                            let senderId = data["senderId"] as! String
                            let recipientId = data["recipientId"] as! String
                            var name: String?
                            var preurl = ""
                            print("the recipient id \(recipientId)")
//                          Constants.refs.databaseUser.child(recipientId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {snap in
//                              print(snap.value as Any)
//                                  let da = snap.value as! [String: Any]
//                                      name = da["name"] as! String
//                                      preurl = da["name"] as! String
//                          })


                            var url = ""
//                          Constants.refs.databaseUser.child(recipientId).child("name").observe(.value, with: { snap1 in
//                              print("")
//                              name = snap1.value as? String
//                          })
//                          Constants.refs.databaseUser.child(recipientId).child("image").observe(.value, with: { snap2 in
//                              preurl = snap2.value as! String
//                          })
                            if senderId == String(requestManager.instance.user.id!){
                                url = Router.baseURLString + (requestManager.instance.user.image?.path.replacingOccurrences(of: "images", with: "/photo"))!
                            }else{
                                //url = self?.rootRef.child("users").child(recipientId).value(forKey: "image") as! String
//                              self?.rootRef.child("users").child(recipientId).child("name").observe(.value, with: { snap in
//                                  url = snap.value as! String
//                              })
                                url = preurl
                            }
```

the code end with a more thing to attach to coreData but that not the question about. the thing is that all the commented code none works both are returning nil for name value and for image gets empty string "". I'm retrieving the chats child with id 121-123. which some child have recipient id equal to 123. so I'm observing user child 12. but get nil always. this behavior is because is asyncronich and the code is passed before the request complete or because I'm reading wrong the users child.
PD: as update Constantref is like this

```
struct Constants
{
    struct refs
    {
        static let databaseRoot = Database.database().reference()
        static let databaseChats = databaseRoot.child("chats")
        static let databaseUser = databaseRoot.child("users")
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the code, and if I am reading it correctly, it appears you iterate over each of the child nodes in chats. Each read in node is then tested to see if the key of the snapshot just read in matches a particular user.id. If that's what the intention is then it's not needed. If you know a specific path then just read it. i.e. if you know you are looking for chats/uid_5, then just read that node in. Keys are unique within a node so there will only ever be one /chats/uid_5 within chats.

Comment: the problem is tha the user data is not inserted in the chat. the thing is that is tha i must do all process after getting the user data because the async in firebase. to make it clear i search child node for key containin some values if that value match , then i need to search in user the specific child value. users and childs are brothers.

Comment: You can't perform a partial string search in Firebase directly, so there is no way to *search child node for key containin some values*. I think there may be better ways to go about this. It's not clear why you don't store user data (like the UID) in the chat so you know who sent the chat message. It's also not clear what issue asych is causing as you have written data to Firebase already so you just need to get it out. Perhaps you can clarify the question as to what you are trying to do and what the specific issue is.

Comment: the thing is that chats has userid-userid as key and then has  fields like recipientId and senderId. with the send id i need to query the users ans ask for the recipientId values to get the name and the image url. if i done all the message append inside the value. i get al data what i need but if not get null o ""

Comment: Are you saying *the thing is that chats has userid-userid as key* meaning the child keys in the /chats node is userid-userid? So "11-126" is a userid-userid? If so, what kind of userid is that? Also, I see that the child of those nodes has a key and then a child 'id' which is an unneeded duplicate. In other words - you don't need a child id that matches the key to the node as the key can always be retrieved from snapshot.key.

Comment: meaning that chats childs has and id wich is useri-user id, so that value is the id of chats. and that chat have conversations. lookup this  {
  "chats" : {
    "11-126" : {
      "-LJZTRGt4lqMFjfgQqH0" : {
        "attachmentType" : 6,
        "body" : "kdnfif",
        "date" : 1533915284798,
        "delivered" : false,
        "id" : "-LJZTRGt4lqMFjfgQqH0",
        "loaded" : true,
        "managed" : false,
        "recipientId" : "11",
        "selected" : false,
        "senderId" : "126",
        "senderName" : "Porter Project
      }

Comment: Please post code in your question, not in comments. It's very hard to read so update the question and let's take a look.

Comment: ok, is not code is just a copy of the json structure to clarify the the id-id thing

Comment: What I meant was that snippets of code/structures should not be in comments - only in the question - your's is there so it's fine. The issue is it's not clear what the structure represents; for example there's a node "11-126" and then "121-123"; neither of which are Firebase uid's and appear to be unrelated. HOWEVER, looking at your users node it appears you're using some kind of custom user number system. I would suggest you don't do that. Use the uid assigned to each user by Firebase in the /users node. It makes everything much easier; authentication, referencing the user in other nodes etc.

Comment: I'm going to take a stab as re-stating the question. You have a chat app and if user B chats user A, user A needs to be notifiied of that chat and who (their info) is chatting them. In code what this means is user A adds an obsever on the chats node for any chat that contains their user ID. Once a chat event is received, you want to look up user B's info within that Firebase closure. Is that right?